# Objects not being interpretted correctly JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Even though the console logs indicate that the value(s) inside the object has changed, the height of the div does not change correctly. What is this a result of? I'm expecting that it will change according to the number of 0's inside the object. For instance, if there's one 0, then it will decrease to 25px, and if there are zero 0's, it would decrease to 0px. However, it always decreases to 50px even if all inputs are filled. Why?

https://jsfiddle.net/r4gf716f/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = {
    userLength: 0,
    passLength: 0,
  };

  $('#username').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#username').val().length < 6) {
      $('#para').html('too short - user');
      obj.userLength = 0;
      console.log('failed user');
    } else {
      $('#para').html('');
      obj.userLength = 1;
      console.log('WORKINGUSER');
    }
  })

  $('#password').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#password').val().length < 6) {
      $('#para').html('too short - pass');
      obj.passLength = 0;
      console.log('failed pass');
    } else {
      $('#para').html('');
      obj.passLength = 1;
      console.log('passed user');
    }
  })


  var errorCount = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
    return (obj[key] === 0);
  }).length;

  if (errorCount > 0) {

    $('.color').css("height", +errorCount * 25 + "px");
    console.log(errorCount);
  }

})
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <p id='para'>

  </p>

  <input type='text' id='username' placeholder='u'>
  <input type='text' id='password' placeholder='p'>

  <div class='color'>

  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.color {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 2s;
}
```

Comment: Your `$('.color').css("height", ...)` line only runs once, ever, because the `$(document).ready` callback its inside of runs only once ever. You probably  want to run it inside your `change` handlers as well?

Comment: @apsillers yes, would I use a loop for this or? what do you suggest?

Comment: Use onchange with a callback function, something like: <input onchange="myFunction"></input>

Comment: Another solution is to upgrade your site to Vue.js, it's designed with the exact thing you're trying to do in mind, synchronizing content based on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like apsillers says it only runs once. I created a function for you to do the checking. you just call it at the start and when you want to check the errors.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = {
    userLength: 0,
    passLength: 0,
  };
checkErrors();
  $('#username').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#username').val().length < 6) {
      $('#para').html('too short - user');
      obj.userLength = 0;
      console.log('failed user');
    } else {
      $('#para').html('');
      obj.userLength = 1;
      console.log('WORKINGUSER');
    }
    checkErrors();
  })

  $('#password').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#password').val().length < 6) {
      $('#para').html('too short - pass');
      obj.passLength = 0;
      console.log('failed pass');
    } else {
      $('#para').html('');
      obj.passLength = 1;
      console.log('passed user');
    }
    checkErrors();
  })

function checkErrors(){
    var errorCount = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
      return (obj[key] === 0);
    }).length;

    if (errorCount > 0) {

      $('.color').css("height", errorCount * 25 + "px");
      console.log(errorCount);
    }
}
})
```

**Edit:**

If you want it the .color div to be 0px this would be the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  var obj = {
    userLength: 0,
    passLength: 0,
  };
checkErrors();
  $('#username').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#username').val().length < 6) {
      $('#para').html('too short - user');
      obj.userLength = 0;
      console.log('failed user');
    } else {
      $('#para').html('');
      obj.userLength = 1;
      console.log('WORKINGUSER');
    }
    checkErrors();
  })

  $('#password').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#password').val().length < 6) {
      $('#para').html('too short - pass');
      obj.passLength = 0;
      console.log('failed pass');
    } else {
      $('#para').html('');
      obj.passLength = 1;
      console.log('passed user');
    }
    checkErrors();
  })

function checkErrors(){
    var errorCount = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
      return (obj[key] === 0);
    }).length;


      $('.color').css("height", errorCount * 25 + "px");
      console.log(errorCount);
}
})
```

Comment: If you want the `.color` to be 0px when there are no errors just get rid of the `if(errorrCount >0)` or add an else statement. Your preference.

Comment: Why would the length never be 0? At one point, if both inputs are filled, both keys inside the var obj should have a value of 1 meaning a length of 0? No?

Comment: @KizakiShabuto I have edited my answer. The reason why in the original is because the `if` operation stops the code inside from executing if `error.length` is 0.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!